# Compare button text

Tags: android, text, button, if-statement, compare

Ok my pattience is gone now...I tried for 30 minutes to make this simple thing work but I failed so bad.Maybe it is because I started directly with android,no java...I studied c++ before,and in c++ this was so easy to do...

I have a button in a xml file:

```
   <Button android:text="Button" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/button1" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
   android:layout_marginBottom="108dp">
   </Button>
```

And in my java file I have a string like this:

```
   String test = new String();
   test = "google";
```

I 've already set up the onclick listener for the button so there is no problem.
My question is if:

```
  Button buttonx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

How can I compare if onClick(onclick code is already made) buttonx's text = the string test that is "google".

I tried with getText,setText...but nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. First things first: `String`s are completely different in Java to C++. In fact, Objects are pretty different all-round.

```
String test = new String();
test = "google";
```

does not do what you think it does.

What this does is create a new empty `String` object and store a reference to it in `test`. The next line stores a reference to a constant String "google" in `test` and makes the empty `String` you constructed in the previous line eligible for garbage collection. This is completely different to C++, where the second line would actually call the `=` operator on the `String` class. You can kinda think of everything in Java being a pointer (but not really), so assignment in Java behaves like pointer assignment in C++ (but not really).

Back to your question.

Something like this might work:

```
String test = "google";
Button b = ...;
if (test.equals(b.getText()) {
    // whatever
}
```

Remember that although Java and C++ share some syntax similarities they are really completely different languages. Java references kinda behave like pointers, but not really.

Really.

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = new String();
test = "google";

Button buttonx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
if (test.equals(buttonx.getText())) {
    // it's equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (button.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(test))
  Toast.makeText(this, "Button text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
  Toast.makeText(this, "Button text is not the same.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```